# Add Pages dynamically depending on per record content in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report, reporting

I am working on crystal reports and facing an issue:

In my case multiple records are coming from db, and I am showing each record on a different page, but I don't know how to do that if one record is too big for a single page.

What I want is that show rest of record into different page with a **continue label** at the bottom of each page. I also want to show page numbers in this format **`page n of p`** on the rest of the pages of that particular record.

Is it possible, and if so, how can I achieve this with crystal report?

here is rough image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can place the data in text field and enable can grow option, set value to 0.

To display pages you need to use `page N of M` special field. Place this as required.l........

Comment: i have already done what you told me to do but the problem i am facing is that when a particular record comes with huge amount of data the first page of crystal report leaves blank and  the data goes to second page and onward

Comment: In this case you need to split the whole string to parts and then display in report...have you tried this way?

Comment: how to split string? would you like to more elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use *Group Expert* to group the records by a unique field for each record.
2. Set your header text in the *Group Header* section
3. Insert `Page N of M` in the *Group Header* section
4. Set suppression formula for `Page N of M` as `PageNumber = 1`
5. Insert *Text Object* in *Page Footer* section and set its *Text* as `Continue ...`
6. Set this *Text Object's* suppression formula as `TotalPageCount = 1`
7. Enable (checked) `New Page After`, `Reset Page Number After` and `Suppress Blank Section` options of *Group Footer* in *Section Expert*
8. If required, enable (checked) `Suppress Blank Section` options of *Page Footer* in *Section Expert*
9. Unckeck `Keep Together` option of *Group Header* and *Details* sections in *Section Expert*